# React not setting state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function where if the user gets the correct answer I update the score

firstly is this the right way to do this: 
`this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 }` I figure it may not be

Secondly, this function increments the score but not the first time for some reason.
I appreciate this is only one function so hard to follow but can answer questions people have on the code:

```
countScore(enteredValue) {
    const { quizData, possibleAnswerTotal} = this.props;
    const { score, correctlyEnteredAnswers } = this.state;
    let index;
    let submittedValue;
    let toNum;
    submittedValue = enteredValue.toLowerCase();
    if (quizData.includes(submittedValue)) {
      correctlyEnteredAnswers.push(submittedValue);
      this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 }) //this works just not the first time
      index = quizData.indexOf(submittedValue);
      quizData.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(quizData, 'qd');
      this.changeBackgroundColorCorrectAnswer();
      toNum = Number(possibleAnswerTotal)
      console.log(score, 'scoressss');
      if (score != 0 && score === toNum) {
        console.log('here');
        this.quizCompleted();
      }
    } else {
      this.changeBackgroundColorInCorrectAnswer();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

By design, `setState` is asynchronous - this allows for optimizations such as batched updates, delaying updates to components that are off screen, and so on. If you want to ensure some code gets called *only* after the state has actually been updated, you can pass a callback as the second argument. For similar reasons, it's also recommended that you use the updater function form if you're relying on the state/props in your call to `setState`.

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return {
        score: prevState.score + 1
    };
}, () => {
    console.log("state updated");
});
```

Comment: this makes sense and should work yet the log isn't coming out and the log further down is staying score is 0 when it should be 1? :/

Comment: ok it is console logging now but still score isn't quite right,

Comment: also interestingly, state updated is logging underneath `console.log(score, 'scoressss');` in my code

Comment: @TheWalrus: You're also mutating your props when you splice `quizData`, and mutating state directly again when you push into `correctlyEnteredAnswers`.

Comment: A quick read of the function and I feel like it's _way_ too heavy for a component method. I don't think there should be a callback passed into the setState at all. This method should be concerned primarily with the logic of counting if an answer was correct or not, and the last line should be the `setState` with the new `score`, and `correctlyEnteredAnswers`. You should also never mutate your props like that (`quizData`), so you'll need another state prop to track which questions have been answered. Once those props are updated, your render handles the rest. That's the point of React.

Answer (score -3):

The setState function does not update the state object immediately.

Use `this.setState` function only if you want to re-render the component. Otherwise just update the state's property directly: `this.state.score++`

Comment: This is bad advice. You should never mutate the component state directly - [the documentation advises that doing so can cause your updates to be overridden by later calls to `setState`.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state)

Comment: `state` is special and shouldn't be mutated (only set on construction), your React class is still just a class. You're free to manage properties in it however you please (just avoid the Component interface - render, state, props, and lifecycle methods). Handler methods are probably the most common thing you'll do this way. In @the-walrus 's example, `score` I'd need to see the `render` to know 100%, but I'm 99% sure that score ought to be in the state.